# xml is XML is xml is XML

Tags: c#, recursion, interview-questions, xml

I had to write some code for an interview, to print out the name attribute of each node. I started off going in the wrong direction, so I didn't get to finish.  I wanted to finish writing the code, so I created my console app similar to what they had a button event doing.  Please let me know what you think of the code and what I can do better.

```
class XMLRecursionReader
{
    private StringBuilder _outputString = new StringBuilder();
    private XmlNode _root;

    public XMLRecursionReader(XmlDocument xDoc)
    {
        _root = xDoc.ChildNodes[1]; 
    }
    public string ReturnNameAsString (XmlNode node)
    {
        return node.Attributes["name"].InnerXml.ToString();
    }
    public void buildString (XmlNode node)
    {
        _outputString.AppendLine(ReturnNameAsString(node));
        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                buildString(childNode);
            }
        }
    }
    public void PrintOutput ()
    {
        buildString(_root);
        Console.WriteLine(_outputString.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

similar sample to what I was coding against.  but the code needed to be generic and able to go as deep as necessary depending on the document that was fed in, but the structure is always going to be similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report name="ReportName">
    <agency name="agency1">
        <office name="office1"></office>
        <office name="office2"></office>
        <office name="office3"></office>
    </agency>
    <agency name="agency2">
        <office name="office1">
            <agent name="agent Amy"></agent>
    <address name="address line"></address>
        </office>
        <office name="office2"></office>
        <office name="office3"></office>
    </agency>
    <agency name="agency3">
        <office name="office1">
        <agent name="agent Bettie">
            <subagent name="sub-agent bob">
            <phone name="456-789-1230"></phone>
            </subagent>
            <subagent name="sub-agent billy"></subagent>
        </agent>
        <address name="address line">
            <faxnumber name="1234567890"></faxnumber>
        </address>     
        </office>
        <office name="office2"></office>
        <office name="office3"></office>
    </agency>
</report>
```

## The Results:

[image: Output of xml is XML is xml is XML]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One should also add that:

- Both the `ReturnNameAsString` and the `buildString` methods could be `private` as they are not very useful as `public` APIs.
- Additionally `ReturnNameAsString` can also be `static` because it doesn't use any private instance data.
- It would be easier to do it with a `XDocument` because then you can *cheat* which makes it virtually a one-liner:

  ```
  var names = 
      XDocument
          .Parse(xml)
          .Root
          .Descendants()
          .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value)
          .ToList();
  ```

Comment: @Malachi it does work, I tested it in LINQPad myself before posting. You must be careful with the xml, it must not contain any whitespaces before the `<?xml` see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/he-dev/a035cc71d243162b5492b3848df0727f)

Comment: I first had to use `.Load` instead  of `.Parse` and then it gives me the Root error, and I have to use a foreach to get the items out of it anyway

Comment: To match the implementation in the question it should be `DescendantsAndSelf()` so the name of the root is included or just remove the `.Root` instead. But it's hard to tell with no expected output.

Comment: "virtually" a one-liner?! It's a one-liner dude.

Comment: @lukkea haha ;-) yeah, I just _prettfied_ it and un-one-lined it.

Comment: with the `DescendantsAndSelf()` method I still had to use a foreach loop to add them to the String Builder and then print out the string.  but it did work.

Comment: @Malachi you could chain another extension at the end to produce a string `.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (current, next) => current.AppendLine(next)).ToString()` ;-)

Comment: I need to get back into LINQ again....I am rusty.

Comment: @t3chb0t, for some reason I am getting double the results...when you get a chance, this is what I have for the class --> https://dotnetfiddle.net/vXENOO  the `fileLocation` is the location of the XML file.

Comment: @Malachi you are using the `_output` variable as a seed for the `Aggregate` here: `Aggregate(_output, ...)` and then you write this result again in the same variable here: `_output.Append(XDocument...)` doubling it this way ;-)

Comment: OMGOSH, I feel dumb now... I see what I did, thank you @t3chb0t.

Answer (score 13):

### Naming

There are [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) which state that methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. You haven't done this for `buildString()`.

### The code

- The `InnerXml` property returns a `string` hence there is no need to call `ToString()` on the property.
- Because all methods are `public` you should do proper parameter validation. At least you should check if the passed parameter is `null` and if yes throw an `ArgumentNullException`.
- The `PrintOutput ()` method does way too much. It builds the output, writes it to the console and reads a line from the console.
- Because `_root` won't change you should make it `readonly`.
- Calling `PrintOutput` twice results in doubling the printed value because you never reset/clear the `StringBuilder`.
- The method name of `ReturnNameAsString` is too much. Because the method isn't `void` it is clear that it returns something. From looking at the returned type (`string`) it is clear what the method returns. Just call it `GetNodeName` instead.
- The class name `XMLRecursionReader` exposes too much information about the implementation. A user of your code won't need to know that you solve the task by using recursion.
- Both methods `buildString` and `ReturnNameAsString` should be private.
- The `if (node.HasChildNodes)` in the `buildString` method is superflous because you are using a `foreach` to iterate over the `ChildNodes`. If there aren't any `ChildNodes` the `foreach` won't iterate.
- The constructor assumes that the passed `XmlDocument` containes `ChildNodes` which may not be the case.

Comment: Another rationale for the naming - if you later change it so that it doesn't use recursion... then what?